# Wudhu with wet hands/face

Tags: islamic-basis, wudu

Is your wudhu vali if your face or hands are a little wet before? I usually wash my face first to remove any makeup/moisturiser and then I was wondering if my face has to be completely dry before I can do wudhu.

Comment: Do you mean that you wipe your face with wet hands, rather than washing it.

Comment: No it’s because I usually wash my face first to remove any makeup/moisturiser and then I was wondering if my face has to be completely dry before I can do wudhu.

Comment: As is you leave us guessing what you actually mean? In fiqh there's a clear distinction between wiping and washing. In case of body parts that need to be washed the water must clearly run over the body part... If you mean having wet hands or any other body parts before wudu' then why should there be any objection as long as this wetness doesn't come from haram liquids?

Comment: It does not need to be dry before you do your wudhu.

Answer (score 1):

First you should know that we (Muslims) perform wudu' for a purpose.
And to do it right we need to have the intention to perform it.

Wudu' is basically a preparation for the prayer it is a ritual that may help you to leave the matters of this life (dunya) and move to what may help you in your after life (akhirah) the worship of salah.

Wudu' or taharah more generally is not meant to clean your body, but to prepare yourself for the coming worship, else as imam a-Shafi'i said (if I rememeber well) wiping on the upper part of a leather sock does
 make less sense than wiping on the lower part which may normally get easier "unclean", but  only wiping on the upper part is actually the sunnah performed.

So as said in the comments it doesn't play any role whether some of your body parts are not dry before you perform wudu' as now as you perform it you have to do it correctly, even if for example your face is still wet. What would play a role is if you cleaned your face with alcohol for example or any najis liquid. But even that would be "ritually cleaned" by a correct wudu'.